# Image fields or Boolean fields in django forms widgets?

Tags: django, widget, modelform

I am  trying to add an image field in the widgets dictionary but I don't know what is the property for forms to do that. like forms.TextInput what should I use for an image field or a Boolean field?
here the code is giving me error in image property of widgets dictionary.

```
class CreateProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'price', 'category', 'description', 'image']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'image': forms.ImageInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at [FileInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#fileinput) and [ClearableFileInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#clearablefileinput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two [file inputs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#file-upload-widgets) you can use. The `ClearableFileInput` should be used if you are allowed to remove the image (i.e set it to blank/null). If not `FileInput` is the right choice.

Also for booleans the [CheckboxInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxinput) is the default from Django.

```
class CreateProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'price', 'category', 'description', 'my_bool', 'image']
        widgets = {
            'my_bool': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'image': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'accept': 'image/*'}),
        }
```

Rather than overriding all the widgets, it might be better to override `__init__`

```
class CreateProductForm(ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

You can even take this out into a separate mixin or base class for all your forms.

Personally, I would suggest not doing any of this in Python but rather in the HTML template, just so it's clear where the classes come from.